# SOAP Basics What To Do With Request

Tags: web-services, soap

I am taking my first steps into SOAP and Web Services. I learn best by reverse engineering and reviewing existing code. (that and Dummies books).

I have the following SOAP request example from vendor that supplies XML data about their products. My problem, I don't know what to do with the code. (yes, I am that much of a newbie to this side of web development)

```
POST /exatawapi.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: webapi.example.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://webapi.example.com/GetAvailableProductsXML"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
   <GetAvailableProductsXML xmlns="http://webapi.example.com/">
    <brand>All</brand>
   </GetAvailableProductsXML>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to get hold of their WSDL. Then use this WSDL in your development environment to generate the classes. Look at the tutotials below for more detail.

1. [A Java Tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user/tasks/create_client.html)
2. [A C# Tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Generating-a-Web-Service-95ff4e10)